# ArrayList solo me trae solo el primer resultado Android Studio (ListAdapter)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy tomando los sms de mi casilla de mensajes, al recorrer con el do while me trae todo cuando lo muestro en el print, pero al querer armar el listview solo me muestra el primer mensaje y los demás los ignora. Qué estaré haciendo mal? (me fije en muchas publicaciones pero aparentemente está todo bien). 
Por otro lado no tira errores, solo trae uno y los demás no los tiene en cuenta.

```
    private void leerHistorial(){
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(INBOX),null,null,null,null);
    String numeroEmisorGPS = getString(R.string.numeroemisorGPS);
    numeroEmisorGPS = numeroEmisorGPS.substring(numeroEmisorGPS.length()-8);

    //TextView txtmensaje;
    Button btnFollow;
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sms_popup);
   // txtmensaje = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmensaje);
   ListView lv1 = (ListView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.listItems);

    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    assert cur != null;
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) { /* false = no sms */
        do {
            String emisor = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).trim(); //TOMA EL NUMERO EMISOR DEL MENSAJE
            String mensaje = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
             if (emisor.length() >= 8){
            emisor = emisor.substring(emisor.length()-8);
             }
            if (emisor.equals(numeroEmisorGPS)  ) { //consulto si el numero emisor es el del GPS
                items.add( mensaje);
                System.out.println("numeros emisor --> " + emisor );
                System.out.println("numeros emisor --> " + mensaje );

            }

        } while (cur.moveToNext());

    }
    ListAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    lv1.setAdapter(adaptador);

    btnFollow = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnfollow);
    btnFollow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialog.show();
}
```

SMS_POPUP.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cuatrosmsentrada_icon"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#F8F9F9"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/nuevo_mensaje"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
      android:textAllCaps="true"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ListView>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtmensaje"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hola Luis ¿En cuantas ocasiones imprime : System.out.println("numeros emisor --> " + emisor ); ? , si lo imprime en varias ocasiones, eso quiere decir que el problema es en el adapter.

Comment: imprime muchas veces amigo, el problema es en el adapter sin dudas porque acabo de imprimir esa linea ( System.out.println("numeros emisor --> " + mensaje );) justo pegado al adapter y me trae todos los mensajes entre [ ]

Comment: Veo que es correcto lo que haces pero en este caso el problema es el contenedor, de hecho veo que cambias el layout mediante :  myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sms_popup); , podrías agregar sms_popup.xml ?

Comment: Ahi está amigo, la idea es que salte una ventana emergente con los sms nomas. por eso el diseño